# When the sensor event is changed, the ListItem Click event does not fire or responding very slow

Tags: android, events, listview, sensors

I have an application, on which when device is rotated, i.e., when onSensorChanged(), I am trying to display a ListView with some dynamic data populated in it through a custom list adapter. When the device is rotated, the data in the ListView is to be updated in the ListView dynamically accordingly. I am able to generate dynamic data but when clicked on ListItem, the click event does not seem to be recognised.

Why is this happening? When the ListItem is clicked, I want to perform another activity which elaborates the clicked List Item's data.

This is my code,

```
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    TextView txtangle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtangle);
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

        // Log.v("ACCELEROMETER", "ACCELEROMETER");

        mGravity = event.values;

    }

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {

        // Log.v("MAGNETIC_FIELD", "MAGNETIC_FIELD");

        mGeomagnetic = event.values;

    }

    if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {

        float first[] = new float[9];

        float second[] = new float[9];

        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(first, second,
                mGravity, mGeomagnetic);

        if (success) {

            float orientation[] = new float[3];

            SensorManager.getOrientation(first, orientation);

            azimuth = orientation[0]; // orientation contains: azimut, pitch
                                        // and roll
        }
    }
    mycallback(event);
  }

  public void mycallback(SensorEvent event) {

    ListView propertylistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    PropertiesArray = new ArrayList<Propety>(4);
    PropertiesArray.add(new Propety("Banjara Hills",
            "Price: 100000"));
    PropertiesArray.add(new Propety("Jubilee Hills",
            "Price: 200000"));
    PropertiesArray.add(new Propety("Film Nagar", "Price: 70000"));
    PropertiesArray.add(new Propety("Kukatpally", "Price: 50000"));
    PropertiesArray.add(new Propety("Jubilee Hills",
            "Price: 200000"));
    PropertiesArray.add(new Propety("Film Nagar", "Price: 70000"));
     customadapter customlistview = new customadapter(
            PropertiesArray); // customadapter is the Custom List Adapter
    propertylistview.setAdapter(customlistview);

}   //This is the hardcoded data.
```

my customadapter class,

```
 public class customadapter extends BaseAdapter {
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<Propety> PropertiesArray;

public customadapter(ArrayList<Propety> PropertiesArray) {  

   this.PropertiesArray=PropertiesArray;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {

    return PropertiesArray.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return PropertiesArray.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View View, final ViewGroup parent) {

     if (View == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlistview, parent, false);
        }
      final Propety ListArray = PropertiesArray.get(position);
      TextView tvPropertyName = (TextView) View.findViewById(R.id.tvCity);
       tvPropertyName.setText(ListArray.getName());

        TextView tvPrice = (TextView) View.findViewById(R.id.tvprice);
        tvPrice.setText(ListArray.getPrice());

       ImageView imgProperty = (ImageView) View.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
       imgProperty.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

       View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "view clicked: "+ ListArray.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }   // This is not firing. Toast is not being displayed. 
    });
    return View;
}

}
```

I want this data to be updated whenever the sensor is changed or the device is rotated. But this seems to be an Incorrect Implementation.

Can anyone please correct me or suggest a good method. I am a newbie to android. 
  This is very hard to me!! 
  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can anyone please suggest any idea!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an android expert either, but whenever I have this type of problem, I use [the Android logging mechanism](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) , i.e. `Log.d(String tag, String msg)` to help me work out what's going wrong.  So I suggest that you put a whole load of Log.d statements  liberally through your code and use the output to solve the problem.